# Loading dynamic "chosen" select elements

Tags: ajax, jquery-plugins, jquery

I am using the jQuery plugin chosen (by Harvest). It is working fine on (document).ready, but I have a button that, when clicked, uses ajax to dynamically create more select objects that I want to use the "chosen" feature. However, only the original select elements have the "chosen" features, and the new (dynamically created) do not work. I am using jQuery.get to append the new elements. Here is a sample of the code:

```
jQuery(".select").chosen();//this one loads correctly
jQuery("#add-stage").click(function() {
    jQuery.get('/myurl',{},function(response) {
            //response contains html with 2 more select elements with 'select' class
            jQuery('#stages').append(response);
        jQuery(".select").chosen();//this one doesn't seem to do anything :-(
    });
});
```

I was thinking that I need a .live() function somewhere, but I haven't been able to figure that out yet. Any help is much appreciated!

**Note - I am not trying to dynamically load new options, as specified in the documentation using** `trigger("liszt:updated");`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ensure that the `response` elements have the `select` class.

```
console.log( response );  // to verify
```

May also be a good idea to only apply the plugin to the new element(s).

```
jQuery(".select").chosen();

jQuery("#add-stage").click(function() {
    jQuery.get('/myurl',{},function(response) {
        console.log( response ); // verify the response

        var $response = $(response);  // create the elements

        $response.filter('.select').chosen(); // apply to top level elems
        $response.find('.select').chosen();   // apply to nested elems
        $response.appendTo('#stages');
    });
});
```

Also, if `/myurl` is returning an entire HTML document, you may get unpredictable results.

Comment: thank you, I found the problem in the response! The select items were there, but they had duplicate ids so they wouldn't load properly.

Comment: before filter add:
$(".select").empty();
after appendto add:
$(".select").trigger("chosen:updated");

Answer (score 6):

after you code (fill the select) .write this

```
$(".select").trigger("chosen:updated");
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem with Chosen.  I was trying to dynamically add a new select after the user clicks on a link.  I cloned the previous select and then added the clone, but Chosen options would not work.  The solution was to strip the Chosen class and added elements, put the clone in the DOM and then run chosen again:

```
clonedSelect.find('select').removeClass('chzndone').css({'display':'block'}).removeAttr('id').next('div').remove();
mySelect.after(clonedSelect);
clonedSelect.find('select').chosen();
```

Answer (score 0):

one way you can use chosen with ajax:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    type: 'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    cache: false,
    data: search
}).done(function(data){
    $.each(data, function(){
    $('<option />', {value: this.value, text: this.text}).appendTo(selectObj);
    });
    chosenObj.trigger('liszt:updated');
});
```

where selectObj is particular select object

But ...

Chosen is implemented very bad. 
It has several visual bugs, like: select some option, then start searching new one, then remove selected and the keep typing - you will get 'Select some options' extended like 'Select some options search value'. 
It doesn't support JQuery chaining.
If you will try to implement AJAX you will notice, that when you loose focus of chosen, entered text disappears, now when you will click again it will show some values. 
You could try to remove those values, but it will be a hard time, because you cannot use 'blur' event, because it fires as well when selecting some values.
I suggest not using chosen at all, especially with AJAX.

Answer (score 0):

1.- Download [Livequery plugin](http://www.example.com/) and call it from your page.

2.- Release the Kraken: `$(".select").livequery(function() { $(this).chosen({}); });`

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of Chosen dynamically loading new options form database using ajax every time Chosen is clicked.

```
$('.my_chonsen_active').chosen({
    search_contains:true
});
$('.my_chonsen_active').on('chosen:showing_dropdown', function(evt, params){
     id_tosend=$(this).attr("id").toString();
     $.get("ajax/correspondance/file.php",function(data){ 
     $('#'+id_tosend).empty();
     $('#'+id_tosend).append(data);
     $('#'+id_tosend).trigger("chosen:updated");
   });
});
```