# Chosen jquery plugin modification

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hi I want to change dropdown value by click on a tag. I made a function it is changing the the dropdown value but the highlighted class remain on the last previously selected tag. so my question is when we change value the class should highlight appropriate option.

Comment: here is example code http://jsfiddle.net/7vkLv/2/

Comment: @Pulkit: please see example code in my comment

Comment: Are you trying to dynamically set your select value??

Comment: i suggest to use [Select2](http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/) it has more options, events , methods and documentation

Comment: A clarification, which highlighted class are you talking about here?

Comment: @pulkit: first click any a tag, you will see that select dropdown vlaue changed then click on dropdown menu you will see the difference

Comment: you mean the blue border that shows up when the 'select' is under active mode?

Comment: Have a look at here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8349888/loading-dynamic-chosen-select-elements

Answer (score 0):

Okay, not really sure if this is what you're asking for, but I gave it a try.

See if this is what you want.

http://jsfiddle.net/7vkLv/3/

I added

```
closest('div.chzn-container').addClass('chzn-container-active');
```

to the span you're changing data in.

Comment: It is working, how different do you want to the output to be?